# How to animate border using vanilla javascript or css

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I set border-bottom color to grey and add transiton to .3s, and ':hover' effect,so on hover it changes its color to blue. Problem is related with that: when I place my mouse over the element with hover effect the border i set(blue) emerges from top to bottom(falling effect).

[this is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX0C5.png)

Now my client wants border to emerge from left to right on hover and border shouldn't fade away on hover on another list item,it(border) have to 'lag behind' the cursor trying to 'catch on' the cursor and fill the next list item's border positon. I hope I you get what I want. I know that it's not possible to do in css,but i don't know how to do this in js,can someone help me with that and expalain  to me what to do,without using any frameworks like jQuery.

Comment: Could you share your animation code with us in codepen or fiddle or link of that sit?

Comment: You should add a div where your border now showing and animate the width property from 0% to 100%. You should style the div similar to the current border style.

Comment: You can do it without js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate by using the `width` property as Thusitha said.

Here I have attached the [codepen](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/EwyBRX) link for that effect.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #eee;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: all linear 0.25s;
}

/* Expanding Animation Element */
ul li:hover:before {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Homepage</li>
    <li>Style Demo</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not all of my problem,as i said i need border to 'catch' my cursor and no fade away while my cursor moves to the second list item

Comment: In this case you need to use javascript or jquery plugin, Here I have attached the plugin link which may useful for achieving this effect. https://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/

Comment: Can you help me with this effect without using plugins,but on ly javascript itself. Just give me an instruction of what to do or provide me with an article

Comment: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/, Here is the article to achieve this effect, you can just follow the steps mentioned in it. They have explained how it works.

Comment: And also I have attached the GitHub link of the above plugin. https://github.com/codrops/DirectionAwareHoverEffect